# Packaged Electron App fails to Find Node Modules

Tags: webpack, electron, electron-packager, electron-forge

I have an electron project that is setup using [electron-forge](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge). The app works fine locally, and I am trying to package it for distribution on various operating systems. However, when I package and compile the app and try to run it, I receive `cannot find module ...` errors like this:

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module 'electron-compile'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/usr/lib/my-app/resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/my-app/resources/app/es6-shim.js:4:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/my-app/resources/app/es6-shim.js:10:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
```

My build process is as follows:

1. use `webpack` to bundle electron components into a single file
2. package and compile using `electron-forge`

#### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  target: 'electron-main',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js']
  },
  entry: [`${__dirname}/src/main.js`],
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  module: {
    exprContextCritical: false,
    rules: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        test: /.(ui.js|s?css|html|png|jpe?g|ico|svg)$/,
        use: 'ignore-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

#### forge.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  "make_targets": {
    "win32": ["squirrel"],
    "linux": ["deb"]
  },
  "electronPackagerConfig": {
    "dir": 'dist',
    "ignore": [
      "src/scss",
      ".*scss",
      "README.md",
      ".gitignore",
      ".nvmrc",
      "gulpfile.js",
      "forge.config.js"
    ]
  },
  "electronInstallerDebian": {
    "icon": {
      "scalable": path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/icons/debian/Icon.svg')
    },
    "productName": "MyProduct"
  },
  "electronWinstallerConfig": {
    "iconUrl": path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/icons/windows/Icon.ico'),
    "name": "MyProduct"
  }
};
```

What am I doing wrong here? it seems like the `electron.asar` that is constructed doesn't know how/where to find certain node_modules, but it was my impression that they would be included in the bundle created by `webpack`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not use webpack for project created via `electron-forge`. It is not impossible thing, but you'll need various custom configuration to make it work.

`electron-forge` is constructed based on `electron-compile`, which registers on-the-fly transpilation hook in electron process. When you build package via electron forge's preset build script it'll generate correct dependency set along with your module dependency. `electron-compile` is one, it is mandatory required dependency but your webpack config breaks those.

TL:DR;

1. `electron-forge` has own flows
2. run webpack then pkg via `forge` can break thing.

I'd recommend take one way only (between webpack vs. forge), customization to mix it would not be trivial for first time setup.

Comment: I understand what you mean, and this probably means i'll switch to `electron-builder` instead. The electron ecosystem is real spiderweb of optional dependencies and configuration that I'm growing more and more disenchanted with. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Instead of using electron-forge for packaging, you can directly use `electron-packager` which forge rely on. It is matter you try to use forge with your configs, using `electron-packager` directly should work.

Comment: The problem is actually `electron-packager` and the `windows-installer` dependency in particular. My issue is related to this bug: https://github.com/electron/windows-installer/issues/189. The recommended work-around is to use something like `webpack` or `bundlejs`, which is how i ended up with my original SO problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new webpack plugin that you can use with Electron Forge, allowing you to override the base compile of Main and Renderer scripts. Haven't tested it myself yet, as I'm still figuring it out.

[Electron Forge Plugin Webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@electron-forge/plugin-webpack)